# Altium 23 won't create split plane

Tags: altium

I am on Altium 23, a 4-layer stackup, signal-plane-plane-signal. All components are laid out and it's time to get started defining split planes.

I select layer 2 and draw the lines to create a split plane, but no split plane is generated. I have tried a lot and tried to figure out why not, but I can't manage. What am I missing?

I tried both drawing a line from pullback to pullback and also to draw an isolated island in the middle of the layer, but everything to no avail.

I noticed that when in 3D mode, the components are shown, but the PCB laminate itself does not show up. Could that be related? Did I miss something in board planning mode? I mean, the pullbacks are there, right where they should be.

Double clicking on a plane layer does nothing, either before or after I add a split line. It's like Altium doesn't recognize the layer as a plane. But it is set as a plane in the Layer Stack Manager.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction here?

Comment: I found the answer to my problem in this post https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/636010/362436